# Virtualhost configuration for 2nd rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, passenger

I have a Ubuntu/Apache VPS where I have a Rails app running fine. Now I want to add a 2nd Rails app and change the virtualhostso that visiting a subfolder will show the 2nd Rails app.

The Rails apps are deployed with Capistrano to:

```
/home/<myname>/apps/<app_1>/current
/home/<myname>/apps/<app_2>/current
```

The "/etc/apache2/sites-available/default" file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        RailsBaseURI /app_1
        <Directory /var/www/app_1>
          Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>

        RailsBaseURI /app_2
        <Directory /var/www/app_2>
          Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I would expect that repeating the same for the 2nd app would work, but it is not. I forgot how  the contents of the public folder end up in /var/www/app_1?

When I now visit "www.mysite.com/app_2" it says:

> No such file or directory - config/environment.rb

But visiting "www.mysite.com/app_1" does work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have a symlink from /var/www/app_2 pointing to your app in /home/yourname/apps/app_2/current

sudo ln -s /var/www/app_2 /home/yourname/apps/app_2/current

Answer (score 0):

Apache only uses 1 folder as it's document root, so if you just specify 2 apps but not tell apache where to pick up the second it will use the main document root to find the document, so in this case it will route app_2 to the first app.

Try and adding a second vhost all together, the same way you would do if you had 2 different domains pointing each one to the correct folder/URL, have a look at this link.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html